# Battery status in menu bar is not changing though It is charging?

Tags: battery, charging

My Mac book pro 2015 is charging however the battery status is not changing. But when I toggle the button "Show battery status in menu bar" in Energy Saver it shows the correct battery percentage. So the battery status is not showing the current battery percentage value.

But It was working before.

Comment: Although SMC reset includes battery charging issues and indicator lights, I am doubtful about the parentage indicator https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: When you say "But it was working before," what does that mean? Before what? Have you tried something specific already? And just to clarify, if you toggle the Energy Saver button, it will update the battery percentage to the accurate one, but when you uncheck it, it reverts to an incorrect percentage number?

Comment: I actually don't know what strange thing I did. Anyways shutdown solves the problem.